# Searching a table in several databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I figure out a table (say tbl_mytable) lies in which database?

Comment: Which database are you using (MySql, SQL-Server, Oracle, ...)? What do you mean by `several databases`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or above and this is an adhoc thing, rather than a programmatic thing, you can try [SQL Search by Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/SQL_Search/index.htm). It's a free Management Studio plugin.

**Edit:**
Programmatically, you can do it via sp_MSForEachDB which is an undocumented system procedure - so, functionality is not guaranteed to behave the same or even exist between releases (i.e. don't use in production code).

```
EXECUTE sp_msforeachDB 'IF EXISTS(
    Select 1 From [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables where TABLE_NAME = ''tbl_mytable'') 
    PRINT ''?'''
```

This will print a list of database names which contain the table.

Comment: Can this be done using a query. As I somehow dont have installation previlages

Answer (score 0):

I have got partial solution like this:

Select Table_Name From DatabaseName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables where TABLE_NAME like 'tbl_Mytable'

But the above query will search the table in only one database.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of doing it programmatically